# Use Tor as a proxy to access https site

Tags: https, proxy, tor

I have a script which has https capability and also http with proxy capability. How can I use it to access a site on https through Tor as a proxy?

I tried using Delegate as described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/423563/convert-http-requests-to-socks5

But that only works for http sites not for https. Is there a way to access https sites as well?

It is a Lua script running using a Sockets library and OpenSSL library.

Thanks

Comment: Can you simply use [proxychains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601107/what-is-an-alternative-to-usewithtor-that-is-no-longer-accessible/33614822#33614822) to run your script?  Or similarly `torsocks`?  This way you don't have to mess with any proxy configuration.  You didn't specify what type of script it is or how it runs so if it's from the command line you can just use these methods.

Comment: Thanks drew for the answering. I have never seen proxychains I will try to dig into it. My script is a custom Lua script. So if I do http query can proxychains convert it to https and route it via tor?

Comment: Essentially, yes (except for the https part).  When you run a program through proxychains, all of its network activity will be transparently run through the proxies configured in proxychains.  If proxychains is configured with Tor's SOCKS proxy as its sole entry, then everything in the program goes through Tor (including DNS lookups).  If your Lua script communicates with a site over HTTP, it will go through Tor, but ultimately still connect insecurely over HTTP from the Tor exit relay to the destination.

Comment: Is there any way I can do this with https.

Comment: proxychains works with HTTP, HTTPS, or any other network protocol (telnet, SSH), so yes.